# What's the best free video editor for a music slideshow?

Tags: transitions

I am looking for a FOSS video editor to make a slideshow with. I want soemhting that's easy to use with the ability to have standard timed transitions across all clips. What's the best option?

Comment: This question is similar to questions that have been asked before. If you search this website for 'free editor', you'll get some instant answers, without having to wait for replies.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Free video editing software](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/14820/free-video-editing-software)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it is the best idea and the fastest Adobe Premier Pro software
Its great user interface can be the best idea for you
Da Vinci Rizalo and Final Cut software are also great
Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but unfortunately this doesn't answer the question.  The OP is asking for a free and open source solution.  Premiere Pro and Final Cut are neither free, nor open source, and while Resolve is free, it is not open source.